# Writing spec for devise RegistrationsController that will make sure users can't change their role - cryptic error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, devise

I have a rails 3.1 app using Devise and CanCan to mange users and roles. I want to make sure that users can update their password, but not their roles. (So ordinary users can't give themselves an admin role, basically). I have overridden the Devise class "RegistrationsController" with some code like this:

```
def update
  # this is my attempt to stop people from updating their roles
  # and giving themselves "Admin" priveledges.
  params.delete("role_ids")
  super 
end
```

I'm hoping this will prevent hackers from updating the "role_ids" field in the user to change their priviledges. (If there is a better way to achieve this, please say!) My problem is I can't seem to write a spec that will test that this code works. My spec looks like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe RegistrationsController do

    before (:each) do
      @user = Factory(:user)
      sign_in @user
    end

    it "should update the user attributes but not the roles" do
      user_params = {"name" => "new_name", "role_ids" => ["2"],}
      put :update, { :id => @user.id, :user  => user_params}
      @user = User.find(@user.id)
      @user.name.should == "new_name"
      @user.roles.should be_empty
    end
end
```

The trouble is this test doesn't execute. I get an error message like this:

```
Failures:

  1) RegistrationsController should update the user attributes but not the roles
     Failure/Error: put :update, { :id => @user.id, :user  => user_params}
     AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
       Could not find devise mapping for path "/user?id=29&user%5Bname%5D=new_name&user%5Brole_ids%5D%5B%5D=2".
       Maybe you forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block? For example:

           devise_scope :user do
             match "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller"
           end
     # ./spec/controllers/registrations_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I don't understand what the error message is asking me to do. My routes seem fine and my application seems to work otherwise. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your setup

> @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]

For details see [How To: Controllers and Views tests with Rails 3](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29)